# Для чего нужен testBuildType в gradle?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit

Я хочу уточнить правильно ли я понял. Вот есть в градл такое значение

```
android {
...
testBuildType "staging"
}
```

Это указывается для того, чтоб при сборке теста градл знал из какой директории брать эти тесты?

Если допустим мне нужно работать с инструментальными тестами, которые должны находиться в `/src/androidTest/java/` то я в сборке должен указать

```
android {
...
testBuildType "androidTest"
}
```

А если с локальными то соответственно

```
android {
...
testBuildType "test"
}
```

Но что то мне кажется что я что то пропустил))